# returns the preorder list of a tree in python

Tags: python, tree, return, empty-list, preorder

I'm new to python and am trying to write a function that will return the preorder list of a tree recursively. I can get it to get the preorder list, however, it comes with a whole lot of unwanted empty lists from the recursive interaction with the base case.

The code is:

```
def BinPreOrder(T):
    if Is_EmptyBinTree(T):
        return []
    else:
        return BinRoot(T), BinPreOrder(Left(T)), BinPreOrder(Right(T))
```

How can I get an output of a list of just the values of every node (no empty lists or the like)?

Thanks so much,

Comment: `return []` is causing the problem. Just use `if not Is_EmptyBinTree(T):...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want a flat list, not a tuple of tuples as your answer.  The first problem is that

```
BinRoot(T), BinPreOrder(Left(T)), BinPreOrder(Right(T))
```

is a tuple with three elements, not a list.  The recursive calls will also return tuples, so you will end a tuple of tuples.

The second problem is all the occurrences of `None` in your result.  As several people have pointed out already, python functions always return None by default, so you have to explicitly avoid the `None`'s.

Try something like this:

```
def BinPreOrder(T):
    if not Is_EmptyBinTree(T):
        answer = [BinRoot(T)] 
        left = BinPreOrder(Left(T))
        if left is not None:
           answer.extend(left) 
        right = BinPreOrder(Right(T))
        if right is not None:
           answer.extend(right)
        return answer
```

EDIT:  There's a shorter, clearer way to do this.  Instead of letting it return None for empty subtrees, make it return an empty list.  Then you can just concatenate the three lists.  I was focussing on addressing the problems with your code, instead of thinking about the problem itself.  Sorry

```
def BinPreOrder(T):
    if Is_EmptyBinTree(T): return []
    return [BinRoot(T)] + BinPreOrder(Left(T)) + BinPreOrder(Right(T))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `not` operator to reverse the result from your `Is_EmptyBinTree(T)`:

```
def BinPreOrder(T):
    if not Is_EmptyBinTree(T):
        return BinRoot(T), BinPreOrder(Left(T)), BinPreOrder(Right(T))
```

All functions return `None` if no other value is explicitly returned.

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, that seems to return a tuple with many `None`. This is what I get: `(3, (1, None, (2, None, None)), (4, None, (6, None, None)))`

Comment: @user5407287 What's the desired output and what is your input? You should construct your question better, it's hard to give you what you want when all we know is you don't want empty lists.

Comment: I'm trying to get an output of a preorderlist consisting of just the values of every node, if possible. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @user5407287 Can you give a few example inputs and outputs?

Comment: I input a bst with values 3,4,1,2,6 and get out `(3, (1, None, (2, None, None)), (4, None, (6, None, None)))`

Answer (score 0):

**Make a list and return recursively.**

```
def BinPreOrder(T):
    ans=[]
    if T is not None:
        ans.append(T.val)
        ans.extend(BinPreOrder(T.lelt))
        ans.extend(BinPreOrder(T.right))
    return ans
```